# Which combinations of Enum StandardOpenOption are forbidden?

Tags: java

The [Enum StandardOpenOption](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/StandardOpenOption.html) has 9 enum constants: `APPEND, CREATE, CREATE_NEW, DELETE_ON_CLOSE, DSYNC, READ, SPARSE, SYNC, TRUNCATE_EXISTING, WRITE`.

I know that some combinations such as `CREATE` and `READ` do not make sense if put together, but are there other such combinations that are forbidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On [FileChannel.open](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#open(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.util.Set,%20java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...)) you may find more details, but not exactly an exclusion table.

Here is a summary:

- **APPEND**    This option may not be used in conjunction with the READ or TRUNCATE_EXISTING options
- **TRUNCATE_EXISTING** This option is ignored when the file is opened only for reading.
- **CREATE_NEW**    This option is ignored when the file is opened only for reading.
- **CREATE**    This option is ignored if the CREATE_NEW option is also present or the file is opened only for reading.
- **DELETE_ON_CLOSE**   *No restriction*
- **SPARSE**    This option is ignored when not creating a new file.
- **SYNC**  *Works only with writing options*
- **DSYNC** *Works only with writing options*